# What is this instrument that is audible first in this Music video?

Tags: instruments

What is this instrument that is audible first in this Music video? is is like some flute?

Comment: https://img.devrant.com/devrant/rant/r_1379774_h8mc8.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool sound!  I think it's someone humming while playing a flute.

If you try to whistle and hum at the same time, you can also get that same kind of interference sound.

If you recorded a flute sound and vocal separately, I don't think you'd get the same effect.  Unless I'm a sucker, this person performs it live just like it sounds.

Comment: Yep.  It's a bog-normal modern Boehm transverse flute, played while humming at the same time, with generous echo and probably other electronic enhancement.